# You need install the older Java SE 6 runtime environment can open the muCommander

Tags: macos, java

I installed the muCommander in my Mac, but can not open it.

[image]

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

What is the best solution for it?

Comment: Try Commander One from this site: https://mac.eltima.com/file-manager.html, no need for java, there is e free version, works OK. M

Answer (score 1):

Install the current version of muCommander.